# Unable To Set Value In data-endVal="{{ucount}}" of CountUp using Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting number of customers and suppliers to display it on dashboard 
using countUp.js for the counter.

Files Used

AngularJS v1.3.15
countUp.js https://github.com/inorganik/countUp.js v 1.1.1

[Minfied Version Of CountUp 1.1.1](http://paste.ubuntu.com/16507604/)

Controller Code

```
myApp.controller('dashboardCtrl', [
        '$scope',
        'files',
        '$http',
        function ($scope, files,$http) {
            $http.get('../../../Admin/Notification/GetAllNotifications')
                .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.ucount = parseInt(data['ucount']);
                    $scope.scount = parseInt(data['scount']);
                    //alert($scope.ucount);
                    //alert($scope.scount);
                }).
                error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log(status);
                });

        }
])
```

JsonResult that is produced from GetAllNotifications

{"ucount":3,"scount":2}

The Div where data is displayed

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
           <div class="info_box_var_1 box_bg_a">
            <div class="info_box_body">
                <span class="info_box_icon icon_group"></span>
                <span class="countUpMe"  data-endVal="1300">1300</span>
            </div>
            <div class="info_box_footer">
                Total Customers
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

the above code works perfectly for static data but when i pass data using
{{ucount}} in data-endVal attribute it gives error in console : "countUp error: startVal or endVal is not a number"

Comment: Have you tried to use `$scope.$apply()` after setting the `$scope.ucount` and `$scope.scount`?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the error appears beacause get request is asynchronous and $scope.ucount doesn't exist when it try to access? Have try to set initial value for $scope.ucount? like 0 for example

Comment: @Cédric  i printed the value of {{ucount}} in a label and its displaying the value perfectly but that value is not accepted in the data-endVal attribute

Comment: Can you give me the line number of Count Up library that generate the error please?

Comment: Even if when you print the value of {{ucount}} works have try my solution? Because i'm pretty sure that if you set $scope.ucount to 0 at start of your function it's going to work

Comment: i set the value of $scope.ucount to 0 at function start and the error was gone but the value was static 0.

Comment: Ok, so try to use $scope.$apply() after update if it doesn't work i think that the a solution could be to use ng-if, like:  
<span class="countUpMe"  data-endVal="{{ucount}}" ng-if="!ucount">1300</span>
When ucount value is 0 this span is not in the DOM and when the value is update the span is create. I don't think that's the best way to do, but i think that could be works

Answer (score 1):

well i initialized the data in state  and now it is working 
here is the state code

```
myApp.state("auth.home", {
                // this state page title
                page_title: 'Stock Management - Dashboard',
                // this state url
                url: "/",
                templateUrl: '../../../Admin/Page/getPage?path=Views/templateviews/dashboard.cshtml',
                // load state specific js/css
                resolve: {
                    notificationdetail: function ($http) {
                        return $http({ method: 'GET', url: '../../../Admin/Notification/GetAllNotifications' })
                            .then(function (data) {
                                var notificationdetail = data.data;
                                return notificationdetail;
                            });
                    },
                    files: [
                        'uiLoad',
                        function (uiLoad) {
                            return uiLoad.load([
                                // countUp animation
                                '../../../Areas/Admin/assets/js/countUp.min.js',

                            ]);
                        }
                    ]
                },
                controller: 'dashboardCtrl',
                ncyBreadcrumb: {
                    label: 'Home'
                }
            })
```

and this the controller code now

```
myApp.controller('dashboardCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    'files',
    '$http',
    'notificationdetail',
    function ($scope, files, $http, notificationdetail) {
        $scope.ucount = parseInt(notificationdetail['ucount']);
        $scope.scount = parseInt(notificationdetail['scount']);

        //// run scripts after state load
        $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function () {
            // init dashboard functions
            $scope.$watch('countries_data', function () {
                countries_data = $scope.countries_data;
                yukon_dashboard.init();
            });
        })

    }])
```

the ui code

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-6">
    <div class="info_box_var_1 box_bg_a">
        <div id="notficDiv" class="info_box_body">
            <span class="info_box_icon icon_group"></span>
            <span class="countUpMe" data-endval="{{ucount}}">{{ucount}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="info_box_footer">
            Total Customers
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is how you are passing {{count}} to the directive. You probably don't pass it correctly. Because instead of receiving a number you are likely to be sending a string. try using :

```
<span class="countUpMe" count-up end-val={{count}}>...</span>
```

Comment: thankyou for looking into the problem but the error is not solved yet.